# How to see updated Dataframe after I run the code again in Spyder (without doubleclicking from Variable explorer after EVERY run)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

Is there a way to see an *updated* version of my Dataframe every time I run the code in Spyder? I can see the name and size of the Dataframe in "Variable explorer" but I don't like that I have to double click it to open it.

Or is there a way to have the Dataframe (that I have *already earlier opened* by double clicking it) **update** after I run the code again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately this is not possible as of September 2020. However, we'll try to implement this functionality in Spyder 5, to be released in 2021.

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir, would be great if it was implemented. Doubleclicking it every time is too slow imo, so I think I'll keep printing the dataframe to console and stay with Sublime at least for now. Good luck and I'll definitely give Spyder another try later if this feature gets added!

Comment: I don't think is implemented yet?